# RDP RemoteApp in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is it possible to enable RDP RemoteApp in Windows 7 Professional? I successfully used [RemoteApp](https://sites.google.com/site/kimknight/remoteapptool) on Windows 7 Enterprise, but it doesn't work on Professional.

Is there is a workaround to get this (registry edit / updates)?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 Pro simply does not support RemoteApp hosting.. Out of all the enquiries I receive about the tool, by far the most are asking if/how it is possible to get this working on Pro. Many users have tried reg hacks, dll replacements, termserv patches and more, but I have yet to hear of a working solution (hack) to make this work. If you find a way, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

According to the system requirements of the App itself, it says that it requires Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate. From what I can tell the Terminal Services registry settings are missing in Windows 7 Professional, which is preventing the RemoteApp Tool from working properly.